# Adding a separate file for all website content

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, text

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a website in asp.net and c#, i need to have it that all text that is in the site should be taken from a separate file, so it can be changed easily if needed, and for other similar reason.

Hope this id clear.

What is the best way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "text". If it is for button, labels, etc then consider using resource files.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i mean, how do i use resource files? i am new to c#, so ill appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up on resource files, globalisation & localisation. There is a binding expression, similar to <%# that can read the values from the resource files.

This should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fw69ke6f.aspx

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to keep your solution 'un-compiled' and then use resource files.